# controlling a physical device via c#

Tags: c#, device

I want to control a physical device. ie: blink some LEDs or turn a servo. (just so simple that I will connect my LED's legs to USB's legs or serial ports pins and send a signal to one of the LED's leg and lit it and same with a servo.)

Question: How can I make this in C#? How can i send a signal through either usb or serial port? What are the things that I need? and how can I manage it? thanks.

```
 messageBox.Show("How to control a physical device via c# ?");

 messageBox.Show("thanks");
```

Comment: Did you use the code segment to actually try and run code? To give us pop ups?

Comment: Have you tried to use your favourite search engine?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn sorry i didn't get what you are saying. sorry maybe its cuz im new with c#. if you help and enlighten i will be pleased. thanks.

Comment: @Steve i searched but haven't found much. just come up with a device or something like "Arduino". but didnt understand much. and im just asking for a simple thing not so complex. just want to connect my serial or usb port with a LED or serve via wire and want to lit the LED or turn the Servo. if you have knowledge about it i will be pleased if you enlighten Steve.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I don't want to be harsh with my comment, but help you. You are searching for a starting point, but this is not the best site for a suggestion of this kind. While some people will give you an answer like 'use this, or use that', you are the only one that knows your needs. I think that searching on the internet will give you a better understanding of the various tools available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Your serial port like this:

```
  SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 2400, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
  port.Open();
  port.Write(new byte[] {0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF}, 0, 3);
  port.Close();
```

The whole thing will be send bit by bit on one wire on serial port and with additional bits for transmission control.

You can blink LED with this. You need to connect LED to pin Transmit Data and to Ground that is usually the plug cover or one of pins. Check [this](http://airborn.com.au/serial/rs232.html) for reference. You need also resistor to lower the current. 3k [ohm] resistor should do.

Driving small servo motor is possible but not that easy. Its better to control servo with microcontroller connected to Your computer.

You can connect two computers and exchange data with this.

You can burn Your equipment so be careful.

You can also buy or build something like [this](http://www.quasarelectronics.com/8191-3-channel-high-current-rgb-led-controller-serial-rs232-ttl.htm)

EDIT:
Ok, lots of questions.

> QUESTION 1) why its hard? cant i just send a signal to the servo and
>   make it run just like i did on the LED?

Serial port is a communication port so **its purpose is to communicate and NOT to drive equipment**. Its power capabilities are low. This port will store data to send in buffer and send bit by bit. So its extremely hard to shape [PWM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) \ [PPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_position_modulation) [signal to drive servo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aSinais_controle_servomotor.JPG) and after all result are not gonna be brilliant as well. Depending on motor that You have You may need other control method, but it will be hard to implement with serial port as well. If You really want to drive hardware from a port I would advice [parallel port](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4981/I-O-Ports-Uncensored-1-Controlling-LEDs-Light-Emit).

> QUESTION 2) in which cases i burn my equipment? and do u mean i burn my serial port? or i burn LED or the servo?
>
> QUESTION 3) you said "Your PC should also have current limited output"
>   so as you referred if i put a resistor then i can manage this? and
>   does 3k solves in all case?

In case You do not know enough about electrical [circuits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_circuit), [networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_network) and [analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_theory) then You have big chance to damage Your equipment. You can burn all of them and in worst case scenario also Your PC and house! First two problems that You need to worry about are [short circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_circuit) and [electrostatic discharge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_discharge)

Current limited output should lower current when resistors value is too low. This should prevent the damage of serial port driver on mainboard of PC.

3k resistor complies with [serial port specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) requirements (3-7[kOhm] <2500[pF]). It should drop taken current below 4[mA]. So in theory it should solve all cases.

> QUESTION 4) where will i write your code? in to the button1 clicked? i mean lest say i have a winform and a button there, will i write your code in to the button clicked event?

You can open port on opening Your program. Then write to port on button click. Then close port on close program. All the code on button click should work as well.

---

PS.: Its also possible to connect serial port to audio input of sound card and then send data on serial port and record it as audio. It works as simple oscilloscope. (You can damage Your PC with this)

Comment: Do not drive a LED with the serial port. It is not designed to supply power. There is a very good reason serial adapter devices sometimes [will have a PS\2 adapter on them](http://www.computimeonline.com/core/media/catalog/product/cache/31/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/a/cableset_lrg_1.jpg). Serial is not designed to have power drawn on it (unlike PS\2), so you **must** have a separate power source if you are going to feed anything that will be drawing power. Not doing this will cause you to burn out the serial port on your motherboard.

Comment: I mentioned that You can burn Your equipment, but its possible to blink LED.

Comment: I was agreeing, not disagreeing with you. I just wanted to emphasize the warning more.

Comment: Your PC should also have current limited output that will secure Your port, like for example in [MC1488 driver](http://people.ee.duke.edu/~dwyer/courses/ece52/datasheets/MC1488P.pdf), but warning is worth emphasizing.

Comment: @rumburak  thanks rumburak. so i can turn on an LED like the way you say. but you say its hard for a servo. QUESTION 1) why its hard? cant i just send a signal to the servo and make it run just like i did on the LED? QUESTION 2) in which cases i burn my equipment? and do u mean i burn my serial port? or i burn LED or the servo?  QUESTION 3) you said "Your PC should also have current limited output" so as you referred if i put a resistor then i can manage this? and does 3k solves in all case?

Comment: @rumburak  QUESTION 4) where will i write your code? in to the button1 clicked? i mean lest say i have a winform and a button there, will i write your code in to the button clicked event? REQUEST 1) is it possible to make a user interface demonstration that turns on a LED and you explain the stuffs and the things you used and make a tutorial and put it on youtube or prepare a document where you explain more and give a link that so that we can look into the document and read and learn more? thanks alot.

Comment: by the way i voted you all up and accepted your answer. and accepted rumburak's answer. and i will be very pleased if he answers above questions also. so that people who look in here can read and enlighten. and i really respect Scott Chamberlain. yet his answer came to complicated for me. but i will be very happy if he can also make a demonstration and explain the things and the microcontroller device he is talking about and show how its made and make a video tutorial.

Comment: @rumburak ah sorry when i accept your solution the questions closes so i unchecked cuz maybe some people may not look inside. so im letting it open for more brain storming and will accept your answer at around 17:00 and my time is 08:35 in here.

Comment: @rumburak WOW what a great knowledge. i really appreciate your effort for trying to explain and help to say more i really respect the knowledge that you have and envy in the knowledge you have in a good way. here its about 16:30 no need to wait 17:00 cuz really nice explanations. thus i accept it and people who search for it may have benefit from Rumburak's answer. just a little question you said it i want to drive a hardware from port you said i would use parallel port. if its possible to write, how will i make it via c# by using parallel port? thanks. its was the final question :P

Comment: Its all in **[link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4981/I-O-Ports-Uncensored-1-Controlling-LEDs-Light-Emit)** that I provided. There is circuit and C# code there.

Comment: oh thanks i noticed. by the way where are you from. your an electronic engineering student?

Answer (score 4):

You need a device that will translate your USB signals to signals your device understands (likely a simple on or off for LED's).

I have used the [U421 in the past](http://www.kadtronix.com/usbhidapi.htm#U4x1Device), they have a library that you just load the DLL using P/Invoke then you can send signals to the pins on the chip. You will then need to wire whatever you want to control to the chip (*correctly*, but that is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow, you may want to try [Electronics.StackExchange.com](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)). See the  `U4x1 Application Notes` section on [the USBMicro website](http://www.usbmicro.com/) for example code and wiring diagrams.

Example code from the webiste:

```
⁄⁄ needed to import the .dll
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public class USBm
        {
        public static byte BitA0 = 0x00;
        public static byte BitA1 = 0x01;
        public static byte BitA2 = 0x02;
        public static byte BitA3 = 0x03;
        public static byte BitA4 = 0x04;
        public static byte BitA5 = 0x05;
        public static byte BitA6 = 0x06;
        public static byte BitA7 = 0x07;
        public static byte BitB0 = 0x08;
        public static byte BitB1 = 0x09;
        public static byte BitB2 = 0x0A;
        public static byte BitB3 = 0x0B;
        public static byte BitB4 = 0x0C;
        public static byte BitB5 = 0x0D;
        public static byte BitB6 = 0x0E;
        public static byte BitB7 = 0x0F;

⁄⁄  USBm.dll - C# pInvoke examples
⁄⁄  "Commands"
⁄⁄      [DllImport("USBm.dll", EntryPoint = "USBm_FindDevices", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_FindDevices();
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern int USBm_NumberOfDevices();
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_DeviceValid(int Device);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_About(StringBuilder About);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_Version(StringBuilder Version);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_Copyright(StringBuilder Copyright);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_DeviceMfr(int Device, StringBuilder Mfr);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_DeviceProd(int Device, StringBuilder Prod);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern int USBm_DeviceFirmwareVer(int Device);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_DeviceSer(int Device, StringBuilder dSer);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern int USBm_DeviceDID(int Device);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern int USBm_DevicePID(int Device);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern int USBm_DeviceVID(int Device);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_DebugString(StringBuilder DBug);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_RecentError(StringBuilder rError);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_ClearRecentError();
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_SetReadTimeout(uint TimeOut);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_ReadDevice(int Device, byte[] inBuf);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_WriteDevice(int Device, byte[] outBuf);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_CloseDevice(int Device);
        }
```

Example of function calling

```
⁄⁄ Test USBm device attached

if ( !USBm.USBm_FindDevices() )
    { 
    MessageBox.Show( string.Format("No Device Present"), "USBm Devices", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information );
    return;
    }  ⁄⁄ implied else

⁄⁄Walk the USBm.dll functions

⁄⁄ some containers
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( 200 );
bool result = false;  ⁄⁄ return values

⁄⁄ .DLL FindDevices  returns the number of devices
result = USBm.USBm_FindDevices();

⁄⁄ return the number of devices
int TotalDevices = USBm.USBm_NumberOfDevices();
int Device = TotalDevices -1;  ⁄⁄ only One device is ever attached so ...

⁄⁄ .DLL About info
result = USBm.USBm_About( sb );

⁄⁄ .DLL Version info
result = USBm.USBm_Version( sb );

⁄⁄ .DLL Copyright info
result = USBm.USBm_Copyright( sb );

⁄⁄ Device Valid
result = USBm.USBm_DeviceValid( Device );

⁄⁄ Device Manufacturer
result = USBm.USBm_DeviceMfr( Device, sb );

⁄⁄ Device Product String
result = USBm.USBm_DeviceProd( Device, sb );

⁄⁄ Device Firmware Version
int FirmVer = USBm.USBm_DeviceFirmwareVer(Device);

⁄⁄ Device SerialNumber [ ]
result = USBm.USBm_DeviceSer(Device, sb);

⁄⁄ Device DiD
int DID = USBm.USBm_DeviceDID(Device);

⁄⁄ Device PiD
int PID = USBm.USBm_DevicePID(Device);

⁄⁄ Device ViD
int VID = USBm.USBm_DeviceVID(Device);

⁄⁄ Device Debug String
result = USBm.USBm_DebugString(sb);

⁄⁄ Device Recent Error - always returns true
result = USBm.USBm_RecentError(sb);

⁄⁄ Device Clear Recent Error
result = USBm.USBm_ClearRecentError();

⁄⁄ Device SetReadTimeout [ sixteen-bit millisecond value]
uint tOUT = 3000;
result = USBm.USBm_SetReadTimeout(tOUT);

⁄⁄ Device WriteDevice [ 8 byte to write (device raw commands)]
byte[] OutBuf = { 0, 21, 3, 65, 8, 17, 60, 0 };
result = USBm.USBm_WriteDevice(Device, OutBuf);

⁄⁄ Device ReadDevice [ ]
byte[] InBuf = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
result = USBm.USBm_ReadDevice(Device, InBuf);

// Device CloseDevice [ ]
result = USBm.USBm_CloseDevice(Device);
```

Comment: This code is epic to any web developer

Comment: @scott chamberlain. it seems really complex to me but i think you showed me a way. so there must be a device if i want to even turn on a LED or turn a servo and not like i connect the LED or servo to the serial port pins or usb pins? did i get you right? by the way i voted you up for the information.

Comment: The serial port can behave as a 1 pin device, but a usb device like I linked will give you 16 pints to do Input or Output. I would recommend getting a USB device and google on wiring LED's

Comment: Oh, and as a side note, you can have up to 255 U4x1 devices attached at once for up to 4080 lines of I/O available.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain  oh i haven't know that serial port behave as 1 pin. QUESTION 1) where did you learned that? i mean where can i refer for this kind of things. for example i may wonder about parallel port also and i do not know how many pin it can have as an output? for this kindof things where you refer? QUESTION 2) since serial port behaves like 1 pin does it mean i can only make one job at a time? so for example i cannot run a servo and turn on the LED at the same time? but how about if i play with the time frequencies so that in veryshort time i lit the LED and then run servo and goes on.